# Installshield 2015 msi when recompiled repair does not recognize existing installed version

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, repair

I have an install script MSI project created using Install shield 2015 professional edition.

Using the MSI that I created I am able to Install, Repair and uninstall within the same build. But as soon as I rebuild the MSI without making any changes to the project the repair option stops working. It says "repair does not recognize existing installed version" though an installed version using the previous build is there in that server.

Can anyone guide me to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: I am pretty sure the cause is what Phil says: **auto-generated package code**. The "solution" is to uninstall from Add / Remove Programs and then install your rebuilt version.

Answer (score 1):

The main probable causes for this is that all MSI files have a PackageCode guid that is unique to the build, and most tools automatically generate a new PackageCode for each new build. The installed product is defined by its PackageCode as well as its ProductCode.

A repair requires the exact same MSI file to do the repair, and that means same PackageCode.  Repair means restore anything incorrect using the original MSI file used for the install. Perhaps you can explain why you would do a rebuild and then try a repair and what your goal is, and note that a repair is not an update or patch of any kind, in case that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks Phil for the response. As you said I was testing update/patch.  By changing the package and product code as you suggested I was able to upgrade by using the install option.